# Prevent navigation on mailto: links

Tags: html, hyperlink, mailto

We have on the public part of our web app some mailto: links in the footer. Someone or something (aka bot) keeps hitting these links and navigating to https://basurl/mailto:some@email.com which results in errors as the webserver isn't happy with the colon in the url.

I assume this is a client setting and outside of our control, correct?

What are the option to prevent this beside obfuscating the link with javascript, also hiding it for bots? 
If this is a defective client and not a bot the javascript solution wouldn't help either.

I could supress this kind of error but this is more preventing the symptom instead of the cause...

Answer (score 0):

> I assume this is a client setting and outside of our control, correct?

Yes.

> What are the option to prevent this beside obfuscating the link with javascript, also hiding it for bots?

It's a bad bot. It probably isn't doing anything good for you. You could examine the IP ranges it comes from and the user agent it sends and block it entirely.